# C# Adding Comments with YouTube V3 API not working

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am using C# and using the YouTube V3 API. I am trying to insert a comment into a video, however it not working although it no error. Anyone can help me, thanks! My code:

```cs
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream("XacThuc\\" + jsonup, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl },
        "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
        );
}

var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
});

CommentThreadSnippet commentThreadSnippet = new CommentThreadSnippet();
commentThreadSnippet.VideoId = dtseReUp.Rows[i]["downloadid"] + "";
commentThreadSnippet.TopLevelComment = new Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Comment() { Snippet = new CommentSnippet() { TextOriginal = mota_edit } };
CommentThreadsResource.InsertRequest commentReq = youtubeService.CommentThreads.Insert(new CommentThread() { Snippet = commentThreadSnippet }, "snippet");
CommentThread tr = commentReq.Execute();
```

anyone can help me Adding Comments with YouTube V3 API

Comment: No errors.... what exactly is the youtube response?

Comment: No response from Youtube yet.  The code runs without errors and completes but no comments have been added

Comment: @HoàngTất post your issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc) - I had a similar problem and in my case, the error was in the YouTube side, so, they might help to figure out if there is a problem with your code or the API itself

Comment: I post my issue on Issue Tracker, I hope this solves the problem, Thank's you!